# Adding cubes of the roots of solution of a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was solving a question paper for pg entrance exam in an university?It is an mcq question
So i came to this question .I don't know which method to use
The question is....

If  $ \alpha ,\beta,\gamma,  $ are the roots of the equation $$ 15x^3+7x-11=0$$ then the value of $ \alpha ^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3$ is (the options are)

1. $\frac{3}{5} $
2. $\frac{7}{5} $
3. $\frac{9}{5} $
4. $\frac{11}{5} $

I did like this
 $$ 15x^3+7x-11=0$$
 $$x^3=\frac{11-7x}{15}$$

And substituted $ \alpha ,\beta,\gamma,  $ and added the three equations but I am not getting a real number.the answer is a real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you get
$$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3=\frac{11-7\alpha}{15}
+\frac{11-7\beta}{15}+\frac{11-7\gamma}{15}
=\frac{11}5-\frac7{15}(\alpha+\beta+\gamma).$$
The value of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ should be immediately accessible
from the cubic equation...

Comment: Should i do it the same way we found this

Comment: Do you know how to write down the value of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ given a cubic equation?

Comment: No.. I dont know..can u please explain

Comment: @NBN If you have a cubic equation $x^3+px^2+qx+r=0$ with roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, then we have the factorisation $x^3+px^2+qx+r=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$. Comparing $x^2$ coefficients: $p=-\alpha-\beta-\gamma$.

Comment: Hint: Look up Vieta's formula for the sum of the roots of a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$ we have $15x^3+7x-15=15(x-a)(x-b)(x-c).$

Equating coefficients, the coefficient of $x^2$ on the RHS above, which is $-15(a+b+c),$ must be $0.$ Therefore  $a+b+c=0$, so $$a^3+b^3+c^3=(1/15)((-7a+11)+(-7b+11)+(-7c+11))=33/15=11/5.$$